# Cordova Local Notification plugin failing with linker command when building project in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm using the [Cordova Local Notification plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) in conjunction with ngCordova. My environment is Xcode 7.2 on OS X El Capitan.

This is what I'm doing (Mac OS X)

```
ionic build ios
open path/to/Project.xcodeproject
```

Then I try to build the project with Xcode and it throws this linker error:

```
duplicate symbol _UIApplicationRegisterUserNotificationSettings in:
/Users/aaronwells/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WorkwellNW-bdstegwryfvyatdpihlpdjnexcnk/Build/Intermediates/WorkwellNW.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WorkwellNW.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate+APPRegisterUserNotificationSettings.o
/Users/aaronwells/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WorkwellNW-bdstegwryfvyatdpihlpdjnexcnk/Build/Intermediates/WorkwellNW.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WorkwellNW.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate+APPLocalNotification.o
```

ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

So I inspected the source files for **AppDelegate+APPRegisterUserNotificationSettings.o**, and **AppDelegate+APPLocalNotification.o**:

**AppDelegate+APPRegisterUserNotificationSettings.h:**

```
extern NSString* const UIApplicationRegisterUserNotificationSettings;
```

**AppDelegate+APPRegisterUserNotificationSettings.m:**

```
NSString* const UIApplicationRegisterUserNotificationSettings = @"UIApplicationRegisterUserNotificationSettings";
```

**AppDelegate+APPLocalNotification.h:**

```
extern NSString* const UIApplicationRegisterUserNotificationSettings;
```

**AppDelegate+APPLocalNotification.m:**

```
NSString* const UIApplicationRegisterUserNotificationSettings = @"UIApplicationRegisterUserNotificationSettings";
```

Okay, so I think the problem is duplicate constant declarations/initializations across source files in the plugin. But why am I not seeing this issue elsewhere for this plugin? What is the recommended way to resolve this issue? Is this an issue with the plugin (in which case I would open an issue on github)? Is it machine specific?

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong versions installed. [cordova-plugin-local-notification](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/0.8.1/src/ios) depends on [RegisterUserNotificationSettings](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-common-registerusernotificationsettings). My Cordova Local Notifications version was 0.8.1, which contained a conflicting object with RegisterNotificationSettings 1.0.1. Once I had updated the local notification to version 0.8.2, the problem vanished.